# Split strings by different delimiting character sequences

Tags: php, regex, text-parsing, preg-split, delimited

I have the following strings, that comes with the format `country:` `Cum name`, `Extra info`.

```
Asia: Asian Cup - Play Offs
Asia: Asian Cup
Asia: World Cup - Qualification - First Stage
Australia: A-League
Belgium: Jupiler League - Championship Group
Brazil: SÃ©rie A
```

The problem I have is how to seperate the information per line using regex.

More specific, from the first line I like to  export the following information:

```
[ Asia, Asian Cup, Play Offs ]
```

From the second the information

```
[ Asia, Asian Cup ]
```

and so on.

For the moment I have try the following statement:

```
^([\w]+\:\s+)[^\-]+(?!\-\s)+
```

It is not completed and I don't know how to continue with this. My primary issue is that I don't know how to negate a part of the statement.

So, what is the way to solve this issue ?

Comment: Can `" - "` be present in first and 2nd part also?

Comment: @anubhava yes, but the second one is for seperating the extra information

Comment: Maybe [`\b\p{Lu}\p{L}*(?:[- ]\p{Lu}\p{L}*)*\b`](https://regex101.com/r/vU7eR2/1)? Before, explode with `\n`.

Comment: Please change your typo in 'cup name',  'cum name' has considerably different meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this regex in PHP:

```
/^(\p{Lu}\p{L}*):\h*(.+?)(?:\h-\h(.+))?$/mu
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dG8nN0/1)

Comment: Do you know how this can be modified for allowing spaces in the first part ? Like `Some Word: Another Word  - Extra Word`

Comment: You can use [`^(\p{Lu}[ \p{L}]*):\h*(.+?)(?:\h-\h(.+))?$`](https://regex101.com/r/dG8nN0/2)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `explode`:

```
$lines = ['Asia: Asian Cup - Play Offs',
          'Asia: Asian Cup',
          'Asia: World Cup - Qualification - First Stage',
          'Australia: A-League',
          'Belgium: Jupiler League - Championship Group',
          'Brazil: SÃ©rie A'];

$results = array_map(function ($i) {
    $ret = [];
    list($ret[0], $tmp) = explode(': ',$i, 2);
    return array_merge($ret, explode(' - ', $tmp, 2));
}, $lines);

print_r($results);
```

Answer (score 1):

First, explose your string on `\n`, then you can use the following regex :

```
([\w\s]+): ([\w ]+)(?:- ?([\w -]+))?
```

> explained here https://regex101.com/r/lV7lT0/1

Comment: Almost done :) But doesn't match the `SÃ©rie` because of the unicode characters. Can this get improved ? Thanks :)

Comment: @MerianosNikos anubhava gave a better one, you can use it

Answer (score 0):

This looks not terribly complicated to me.  You want to split on a colon followed by a space or a space-hyphen-space.  `preg_split()` will be happy to oblige.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/5jumm))

```
$lines = [
    'Asia: Asian Cup - Play Offs',
    'Asia: Asian Cup',
    'Asia: World Cup - Qualification - First Stage',
    'Australia: A-League',
    'Belgium: Jupiler League - Championship Group',
    'Brazil: SÃ©rie A'
];

var_export(
    array_map(
        fn($v) => preg_split('/: | - /', $v),
        $lines
    )
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Asia',
    1 => 'Asian Cup',
    2 => 'Play Offs',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Asia',
    1 => 'Asian Cup',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Asia',
    1 => 'World Cup',
    2 => 'Qualification',
    3 => 'First Stage',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Australia',
    1 => 'A-League',
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Belgium',
    1 => 'Jupiler League',
    2 => 'Championship Group',
  ),
  5 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Brazil',
    1 => 'SÃ©rie A',
  ),
)
```

---

If your input data is actually a block of text, then just use `\R` to split it on the newlines. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Dc9e8))

```
preg_split('/\R/', $text)
```